# Uso do do/while em JavaScript para solicitar 10 números ao usuário

Tags: javascript, array, loop

Minha professora passou um exercício com a seguinte descrição:

> Faça um programa em JavaScript que solicite 10 números inteiros e exiba quantos números são maiores que 50 - usar laço `do while`.

Eu não consegui resolver com o uso do `do while`, então tentei resolvê-lo sem o uso do `do while`, e ficou da seguinte forma:

```js
    
var elementos = []; 
var maior = [];
var menor = [];
var num = 0;
    
while (num < 12) {
elementos.push(parseInt(prompt("Digite um numero inteiro:")));
num++;
}

for (var i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
if (elementos[i] > 50)
  maior.push(elementos[i]);
else
  menor.push(elementos[i]);
}
    
console.log("Existem " + maior.length + " números que maiores que 50!\n");
console.log("Existem " + menor.length + " números menores que 50!");
```

Queria saber se o meu código está muito complexo para o que ela pede, e se de alguma forma está correto e o que pode ser melhorado.

Comment: Uma abordagem funcional não o interessa: `let maior = elementos.filter(e=> e > 50)` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O código me parece razoável (para alguém que penso estar começando), embora existam alguns *problemas*:

1. #### Você não está pedindo 10 números, mas sim 12

   Pode-se observar que, na condição `num <= lim` (na qual `num` é iniciado como `0` e `lim` é definido como `11`), serão feitas, no total, 12 iterações, já que no intervalo inclusivo entre 0 e 11 existem 12 elementos.

   Você pode corrigir isso mudando a condição para `num < 10`, por exemplo, na qual `num` ainda começa como `0`. Note que agora o intervalo é de 0 a 10, exclusivo – que contabilizam 10 elementos no total. Note que, para isso, além de mudar `lim`, alterei o operador de *menor que ou iguala* (`<=`) para *menor que* (`<`).
2. #### Sobre a mensagem de que não existem números maiores que 50

   Analisando esta parte do código:

   ```
   for (var i = 1; i <= elementos.length; i++) {
     if (elementos[i] > 50) {
       maior.push(elements[i]);
     } else if(elementos[i] < 50) {
       console.log("Não existem números maiores que 50!");
     }
   }
   ```

   A mensagem "*Não existem números maiores que 50!*" me traz a ideia de que, do total de números fornecidos pelo usuário, não existe nenhum maior que 50. No entanto, essa mensagem é impressa para *cada* número fornecido pelo usuário que é menor que 50 – o que me parece um erro.
3. #### Cadê o `do while`?

   O enunciado é claro e pede que o laço `do while` seja usado, mas... Cadê?! :P Na realidade, esse laço é (raramente) necessário e pode sempre ser substituído por um `while` normal (como você fez), mas se está no enunciado, a instrução deveria, em tese, ser seguida.

---

Enfim, corrigindo esses pontos, teríamos algo como:

```js
const elementos = [];
do {
  elementos.push(parseInt(prompt('Digite um número inteiro:')));
} while (elementos.length < 10); // Enquanto o comprimento da lista for menor que 10, execute o bloco `do`.

const maiores = [];
for (let i = 0; i < elementos.length; i++) {
  const atual = elementos[i];
  if (atual > 50) {
    maiores.push(atual);
  }
}

if (maiores.length > 0) {
  console.log('Existem ' + maiores.length + ' números que são maiores que 50!');
} else {
  // Note que só exibiremos esta mensagem caso nenhum número fornecido ser maior que 50.
  console.log('Não existem números maiores que 50!');
}
```

Não é um erro, mas como arrays em JavaScript têm a propriedade `length` (que retorna o comprimento do array), não é necessário manter um contador "manual" para saber quantos elementos foram inseridos. Só vá inserindo até que a quantidade de elementos satisfaça alguma condição de parada.

Note que nenhum tipo de validação foi feita para confirmar se o valor fornecido pelo usuário foi, de fato, um número. Se isso for necessário, você pode utilizar funções como [`Number.isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN) aplicadas ao resultado do `parseInt`.

O código acima é bem bruto, embora ideal para quem ainda está aprendendo. Futuramente talvez você aprenda sobre [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro), que pode simplificar o código ainda mais (principalmente tornando o segundo laço, o `for`, implícito).

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo comentário :). Me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 6):

Se você quer **somente** a quantidade de números maiores que 50, sem se importar em quais são, então não precisaria guardá-los em um array. Bastaria incrementar o contador quando o número for maior que 50:

```js
var i = 0, qtd = 0;
do {
    var n = parseInt(prompt('digite um número: '));
    if (n > 50) {
        qtd++;
    }
    i++;
} while(i < 10);
console.log(`Existem ${n} números maiores que 50`);
```

Veja também que usei `do`/`while` para ler os 10 números.

E como o `n` só é usado uma vez, talvez nem precise dele:

```
do {
    if (parseInt(prompt('digite um número: ')) > 50) {
        qtd++;
    }
    i++;
} while(i < 10);
```

---

O que talvez possa ser melhorado (mas não sei se é requisito do exercício) é validar se foi digitado mesmo um número inteiro:

```js
var i = 0, qtd = 0;
do {
    var n;
    while(true) {
        n = parseInt(prompt('digite um número: '));
        if (isNaN(n)) alert('digite um número válido');
        else break;
    }
    if (n > 50) {
        qtd++;
    }
    i++;
} while(i < 10);
console.log(`Existem ${n} números maiores que 50`);
```

Quando `parseInt` recebe algo que ele não sabe como transformar em número (seguindo o [algoritmo descrito na documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#description)), [o retorno](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#return_value) é [`NaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NaN), e aí basta usar [`isNaN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) para verificar se esse foi o valor retornado.

---

Agora, se você quer guardar todos os números (tanto os que foram digitados, quanto aqueles que são maiores que 50), aí tem que manter os 2 arrays. Só que você não precisa de um *loop* para ler e outro para ver quem é maior que 50. Dá para fazer tudo em um único *loop*:

```js
var i = 0;
var todos = [], maiores50 = [];
do {
    var n;
    while(true) {
        n = parseInt(prompt('digite um número: '));
        if (isNaN(n)) alert('digite um número válido');
        else break;
    }
    todos.push(n);
    if (n > 50) {
        maiores50.push(n);
    }
    i++;
} while(i < 10);

console.log(`todos os números: ${todos}`);
console.log(`Existem ${maiores50.length} números maiores que 50: ${maiores50}`);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pelo comentário :). Me ajudou muito!